# Revenge of the RPS game (this time with jquery!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Yes, I realize I'm "that guy".  I'm sorry.

Here's the issue:  I took the Rock Paper Scissors game and decided to try and make it work with jQuery.  The basic idea is that you should click on a button to make a choice for yourself (rock, paper or scissors) and then when you click on the "go" button your selection will be compared to a randomly generated computer selection.  After that, a modal will appear that states if you won, lost or tied.
  I've gone through and put click listeners in the JS, and the buttons seem to be working fine (they will console log what they're supposed to).  I'm not sure what the problem is.  I'm guessing that my "compare" function isn't being passed the proper variables because the modal will load but it just says "ERROR!".

This is the HTML

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button id="rock">Rock</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button id="paper">Paper</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button id="scissors">Scissors</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <button id="go" data-toggle="modal">Fight!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="bigWin" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;  </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Results!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p id="result"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the JS

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   //computer choice logic
  function computerChoice(){
    var choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    var computerRando = choices[Math.floor(Math.random()* choices.length)];
    return computerRando;
  } 

  //button functions
  $("#rock").click(function(){
    choose("rock");
    });
  $("#paper").click(function(){
    choose("paper");
    }); 
  $("#scissors").click(function(){
    choose("scissors");
    }); 
  $("#go").click(function(){
    compare(choose, computerChoice);
  $("#bigWin").modal('show')
  });

  function choose(userChoice){
    if (userChoice === "rock"){
      return "rock";
    } else if(userChoice === "paper"){
      return "paper";
    } else if(userChoice === "scissors"){
      return "scissors";
    }
  }

  //fire off game
  var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Tie!  Train harder!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
      if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have vanquished your enemy!";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have brought shame upon your dojo!!";
      }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {
      if (choice2 === "rock") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have vanquished your enemy!";
     }
      else if (choice2 ==="scissors") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have brought shame upon your dojo!!";
      }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
      if (choice2 === "rock") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have brought shame upon your dojo!!";
      }
      else if (choice2 === "paper") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have vanquished your enemy!";
      }
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "ERROR!";
    }
  }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How have you tried debugging this? Have you used `console.log` or `alert` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `choose()` but never assign the returned value to a variable.

Then you call `compare(choose, computerChoice);` but `'choose'` never exists as a variable.

You should probably look into variable scope in Javascript/JQuery some more as well.

There are some more mistakes in your code. But try to find them yourself.